# QField Geotagged Photos with NULL direction field

Tags: qfield, null, direction, geotag, exif

I have some geotagged photos taken in QField on an Android device. Whenever I import these photos into QGIS using the "Import Geotagged Photos" tool, the "direction" field is NULL, which is a key element for me when geotagging photos. Is this a known issue? I tried using Open Camera, but apparently it is no longer possible to assign a third party camera app as default on Android devices.

Comment: Does your device sense azimuth?

Comment: third party camera app as default on Android [you need to clear the default app first then you set the new default]

Comment: Can you post a picture or the output from EXIFtools or gdalinfo so we can see the EXIF data?